# Saving value in Hibernate to another table than entity table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables `bo_operator` and `hist_bo_operator_password`. In `bo_operator` the `id` column is foreign key to `hist_bo_operator_password` and I can have many the same `operator_id` in `hist_bo_operator_password` and only one `id` in `bo_operator`.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bo_operator")
public class Operator implements Serializable
```

and that's how I am getting values from `hist_bo_operator_password`:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="hist_bo_operator_password", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_operator"))
@Column(name="password")
public List<String> oldPasswords = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but when I'm trying to get only one value by:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="hist_bo_operator_password", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_operator"))
@Column(name="password")
public String oldPassword;
```

I'm getting error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: local.vlex.operator.model.Operator.oldPassword
```

and all I want to do is makeing an insert into `hist_bo_operator_password` by
`operator.setOldPassword(oldPassword);`. I think the problem is that it doesn't know which password take if there is many values for the same `id`.
How to achive it?

@Edit
I also tried:

```
@Table(name="bo_operator")
@SecondaryTable(name = "hist_bo_operator_password",pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_operator", referencedColumnName="id"))
```

I even found ORDER BY so:

```
@Column(name="password", table="hist_bo_operator_password")
@OrderBy("data_ins")
public String oldPassword;
```

but seems like there is no @Limit or something like this in JPA and I still have many values to the same id which cause error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Duplicate identifier in table for: [local.vlex.operator.model.Operator#1]
```

Comment: `@ElementCollection` is used for collection, not for single value type. Btw why do you want to get only one value (while you're using a collection)? and you can make an insert by just add `oldPassword` to your list! I don't know if I'm getting your idea?

Comment: Generally, I wanted something what @Andriy Slobodyanyk wrote so accepted the answer. There is saving whole list and I just wanted to get one (the earliest) value and make insert with it but it is oke, I made trigger on table and when the new value is comming then the earliest are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described at the first sentence you have one-to-many relationship

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="hist_bo_operator_password", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_operator"))
@Column(name="password")
@OrderBy("data_ins")
public List<String> oldPasswords = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then add necessary getter

```
Optional<String> getPassword() {
    return oldPasswords.size() > 0
        ? Optional.of(oldPasswords.get(0))
        : Optional.empty();
}
```

And setter

```
void setPassword(String password) { // or maybe addPassword?
    oldPasswords.add(password);
}
```

Comment: Okey, that's how I can get the last password but I would also set this oldPassword to use save on Operator object later. The goal is to make an insert to `hist_bo_operator_password` this code would save the whole list.

Comment: @Michu93, well, add setter, modified the code above

Comment: That's close what I expect but it is saving the whole list instead of just one value. I think there is needed some limit or annotation to oldPassword. Now we are trying to do everything on list.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create entity of hist_bo_operator_password? 
Then you could have List of that entities (instead of just String List) and just add another object to List and save entity Operator.

Comment: I just need one column from `hist_bo_operator_password` so I think new @Entity for that is not needed